# Flutter: Why Future.then() doesn't work on class variable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, future

Code I show you is the simplified code which I'm troubled in.

My expected result is [1,2,3,4,5,6], but app says [1,2,3].

I know "loadMoreInterger()" should be in "initState()", but for some reason I have to put it in Widget build() {"HERE"}.

I wonder if why doesn't it work, and the solution for correct result.....
I really appreciate for your help :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

// ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓WHERE I CANNOT UNDERSTAND↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<int> intList = [1,2,3];

  Future<List<int>> loadMoreInteger() async {
    print('Future');
    return [4,5,6];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    loadMoreInteger().then((value) {
      intList.addAll(value); // why doesn't it work?
    });
    print("console: $intList");

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("display: $intList")
      )
    );
  }
}

//Expected result: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
//Actual result: [1,2,3]
```

Comment: coz you dont return a future data, you return static data

Comment: try  loadMoreInteger().then((value) {
      intList.add(value); 
    });

Comment: @MuratAslan I'm sorry for bothering you. Can you describe your words in more detail?

Comment: @GirlWhoCode Datatype of "value" and "intList" is List<int>. So I cannot use 'add' metod... Thank you for your attention, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your `build` method does: after entering the method it starts to execute `loadMoreInteger()` future. Afterwards even if executed future is synchronous it only *schedules call* of next future that is produced by calling `.then`. So `build` method continues to execute with old `intList` value. And `[4,5,6]` will be added only after `build` completes.

In general you can wait for future to complete by calling it with `await` keyword. But `build` method is overriden and already has predefined return type that is not future, so you can not call `await` inside `build`.

What you can do:
I highly recommend moving any manipulation with data from `build` method. Its purpose is to produce widgets as fast as possible. It can be called multiple times at some moment unexpected for developer.
One of possible options for you will be moving `loadMoreInteger()` to `initState` and calling `setState` when `intList` is updated

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loadMoreInteger().then((value) {
    setState(() {
      intList.addAll(value); 
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I was finding an alternation of putting loadMoreInteger() into initState()... but I think there is no way easy, I think. I really appreciate for your help. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

put it in initState override function  and it works for yu !!!!

```
 List<int> intList = new List();
  Future<List<int>> loadMoreInteger() async {
    print('Future');
    return [4,5,6];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    intList = [1,2,3];
    loadMoreInteger().then((v){
      setState(() {
        intList.addAll(v) ;
      });
    }); }
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I have to find alternation of putting loadMoreInteger() into initState(). But I think it's not as easy as I thought. Thank you for your help!!!